# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [64,256,154,1] vs. [64,256,160,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I'm currently trying to train my VAE (variational autoencoder) on my snare one-shot audio data. I'm running into dimension mismatches.

I have inspected my data and it is (158, 256, 154, 1) where there is 158 samples (small i know i just want to get it working first) 256 is n_bins, and 154 is n_frames and 1 denotes the spectrogram as a greyscale image.

I'm unsure how to update my convolutional layers to account for the new data.

Below is my training script with defines the parameters

'

```
class VAE:
    """
    VAE represents a Deep Convolutional variational autoencoder architecture
    with mirrored encoder and decoder components.
    """

def __init__(self,
             input_shape,
             conv_filters,
             conv_kernels,
             conv_strides,
             latent_space_dim):
    self.input_shape = input_shape # [28, 28, 1]
    self.conv_filters = conv_filters # [2, 4, 8]
    self.conv_kernels = conv_kernels # [3, 5, 3]
    self.conv_strides = conv_strides # [1, 2, 2]
    self.latent_space_dim = latent_space_dim # 2
    self.reconstruction_loss_weight = 1000000

    self.encoder = None
    self.decoder = None
    self.model = None

    self._num_conv_layers = len(conv_filters)
    self._shape_before_bottleneck = None
    self._model_input = None

    self._build()

def summary(self):
    self.encoder.summary()
    self.decoder.summary()
    self.model.summary()

def compile(self, learning_rate=0.0001):
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                       loss=self._calculate_combined_loss)
                       #metrics=[self._calculate_reconstruction_loss,
                               # self._calculate_kl_loss])

def train(self, x_train, batch_size, num_epochs):
    self.model.fit(x_train,
                   x_train,
                   batch_size=batch_size,
                   epochs=num_epochs,
                   shuffle=True)

def save(self, save_folder="."):
    self._create_folder_if_it_doesnt_exist(save_folder)
    self._save_parameters(save_folder)
    self._save_weights(save_folder)

def load_weights(self, weights_path):
    self.model.load_weights(weights_path)

def reconstruct(self, images):
    latent_representations = self.encoder.predict(images)
    reconstructed_images = self.decoder.predict(latent_representations)
    return reconstructed_images, latent_representations

@classmethod
def load(cls, save_folder="."):
    parameters_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "parameters.pkl")
    with open(parameters_path, "rb") as f:
        parameters = pickle.load(f)
    autoencoder = VAE(*parameters)
    weights_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "weights.h5")
    autoencoder.load_weights(weights_path)
    return autoencoder

def _calculate_combined_loss(self, y_target, y_predicted):
    reconstruction_loss = self._calculate_reconstruction_loss(y_target, y_predicted)
    kl_loss = self._calculate_kl_loss(y_target, y_predicted)
    combined_loss = self.reconstruction_loss_weight * reconstruction_loss\
                                                     + kl_loss
    return combined_loss

def _calculate_reconstruction_loss(self, y_target, y_predicted):
    error = y_target - y_predicted
    reconstruction_loss = K.mean(K.square(error), axis=[1, 2, 3])
    return reconstruction_loss

def _calculate_kl_loss(self, y_target, y_predicted):
    kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + self.log_variance - K.square(self.mu) -
                           K.exp(self.log_variance), axis=1)
    return kl_loss

def _create_folder_if_it_doesnt_exist(self, folder):
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)

def _save_parameters(self, save_folder):
    parameters = [
        self.input_shape,
        self.conv_filters,
        self.conv_kernels,
        self.conv_strides,
        self.latent_space_dim
    ]
    save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "parameters.pkl")
    with open(save_path, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(parameters, f)

def _save_weights(self, save_folder):
    save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "weights.h5")
    self.model.save_weights(save_path)

def _build(self):
    self._build_encoder()
    self._build_decoder()
    self._build_autoencoder()

def _build_autoencoder(self):
    model_input = self._model_input
    model_output = self.decoder(self.encoder(model_input))
    self.model = Model(model_input, model_output, name="autoencoder")

def _build_decoder(self):
    decoder_input = self._add_decoder_input()
    dense_layer = self._add_dense_layer(decoder_input)
    reshape_layer = self._add_reshape_layer(dense_layer)
    conv_transpose_layers = self._add_conv_transpose_layers(reshape_layer)
    decoder_output = self._add_decoder_output(conv_transpose_layers)
    self.decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_output, name="decoder")

def _add_decoder_input(self):
    return Input(shape=self.latent_space_dim, name="decoder_input")

def _add_dense_layer(self, decoder_input):
    num_neurons = np.prod(self._shape_before_bottleneck) # [1, 2, 4] -> 8
    dense_layer = Dense(num_neurons, name="decoder_dense")(decoder_input)
    return dense_layer

def _add_reshape_layer(self, dense_layer):
    return Reshape(self._shape_before_bottleneck)(dense_layer)

def _add_conv_transpose_layers(self, x):
    """Add conv transpose blocks."""
    # loop through all the conv layers in reverse order and stop at the
    # first layer
    for layer_index in reversed(range(1, self._num_conv_layers)):
        x = self._add_conv_transpose_layer(layer_index, x)
    return x

def _add_conv_transpose_layer(self, layer_index, x):
    layer_num = self._num_conv_layers - layer_index
    conv_transpose_layer = Conv2DTranspose(
        filters=self.conv_filters[layer_index],
        kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[layer_index],
        strides=self.conv_strides[layer_index],
        padding="same",
        name=f"decoder_conv_transpose_layer_{layer_num}"
    )
    x = conv_transpose_layer(x)
    x = ReLU(name=f"decoder_relu_{layer_num}")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(name=f"decoder_bn_{layer_num}")(x)
    return x

def _add_decoder_output(self, x):
    conv_transpose_layer = Conv2DTranspose(
        filters=1,
        kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[0],
        strides=self.conv_strides[0],
        padding="same",
        name=f"decoder_conv_transpose_layer_{self._num_conv_layers}"
    )
    x = conv_transpose_layer(x)
    output_layer = Activation("sigmoid", name="sigmoid_layer")(x)
    return output_layer

def _build_encoder(self):
    encoder_input = self._add_encoder_input()
    conv_layers = self._add_conv_layers(encoder_input)
    bottleneck = self._add_bottleneck(conv_layers)
    self._model_input = encoder_input
    self.encoder = Model(encoder_input, bottleneck, name="encoder")

def _add_encoder_input(self):
    return Input(shape=self.input_shape, name="encoder_input")

def _add_conv_layers(self, encoder_input):
    """Create all convolutional blocks in encoder."""
    x = encoder_input
    for layer_index in range(self._num_conv_layers):
        x = self._add_conv_layer(layer_index, x)
    return x

def _add_conv_layer(self, layer_index, x):
    """Add a convolutional block to a graph of layers, consisting of
    conv 2d + ReLU + batch normalization.
    """
    layer_number = layer_index + 1
    conv_layer = Conv2D(
        filters=self.conv_filters[layer_index],
        kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[layer_index],
        strides=self.conv_strides[layer_index],
        padding="same",
        name=f"encoder_conv_layer_{layer_number}"
    )
    x = conv_layer(x)
    x = ReLU(name=f"encoder_relu_{layer_number}")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(name=f"encoder_bn_{layer_number}")(x)
    return x

def _add_bottleneck(self, x):

    """Flatten data and add bottleneck with Guassian sampling (Dense
    layer).
    """

    self._shape_before_bottleneck = K.int_shape(x)[1:]
    x = Flatten()(x)
    self.mu = Dense(self.latent_space_dim, name="mu")(x)
    self.log_variance = Dense(self.latent_space_dim,
                              name="log_variance")(x)

    def sample_point_from_normal_distribution(args):
        mu, log_variance = args
        epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(self.mu), mean=0.,
                                  stddev=1.)
        sampled_point = mu + K.exp(log_variance / 2) * epsilon
        return sampled_point

    x = Lambda(sample_point_from_normal_distribution,
               name="encoder_output")([self.mu, self.log_variance])
    return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    autoencoder = VAE(
        input_shape=(, 28, 1),
        conv_filters=(32, 64, 64, 64),
        conv_kernels=(3, 3, 3, 3),
        conv_strides=(1, 2, 2, 1),
        latent_space_dim=2)
    autoencoder.summary()
```

'

This is what i have defined the VAE as in my training script:

'

```
def train(x_train, learning_rate, batch_size, epochs):
    autoencoder = VAE(
        input_shape=(256, 154, 1), #changed from 256, 64, 1
        conv_filters=(512, 256, 128, 64, 32),
        conv_kernels=(3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
        conv_strides=(2, 2, 2, 2, (2, 1)), 
        latent_space_dim=128)
    autoencoder.summary()
    autoencoder.compile(learning_rate)
    autoencoder.train(x_train, batch_size, epochs)
    return autoencoder
```

'

Comment: Your code does not run for me, but seems like your model output could be of shape `(256,160,1)`. Did you check `model.summary()`?

Comment: It was the decoder part of the model, I sorted it thanks